# How do I rotate my camera view back to normal in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my app, I have an option to reset the user's view.
It takes the camera position back to the initial position, say (0,0,0). However, if before clicking on reset, the user had rotated the view of the camera (I have certain mouse actions to rotate the camera), after clicking on reset, the camera position goes back to (0,0,0) but the rotation remains the same.

How do I rotate it back to normal? (Where normal is in a completely un-rotated state, viewing straight ahead)

Comment: First result from a simple Google search... https://answers.unity.com/questions/258911/setting-main-camera-rotation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you reset the position, but not the rotation.

To reset the rotation:

```
_yourCamera.transform.rotation = Quarterion.identity;
```

You can also use the property of the main camera if we're talking about the camera tagged as "Main".

```
Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quarterion.identity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "lookAt" transform method to rotate your camera and look again to the object you had initially.

```
// Rotate the camera every frame so it keeps looking at the target
transform.LookAt(target);
```